# Delete files in temp folder associated with process

Tags: java, linux, processbuilder, temp

I'm killing process via Java code like:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", String.format("kill %s", pid));
process = processBuilder.start();
process.waitFor();
```

And after that I need to delete all temp files and folders that was created by this process. My question is how that can be done?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can get a list of temp files that were created by your process. Consider deleting these files from your process itself

Comment: @coolguy I can't know which folders were created by it exactly, because it is external process. Solution with deleting folders, which are currently associated with this process would also be great.

Comment: Quick and dirty solution, should be write a log of files created by process and than try to remove each created, or if it is possible do it as @blahfunk said, it seems less error prone.

Comment: Can you create a tmp directory to run the process and then just remove that directory? Will that cover all the files it would have created?

Comment: @blahfunk no, I can't. They are created in temp folder and I cannot override that.

Comment: @bodo since it is external process I cannot impact on it's logic. I just start and kill it and when I kill it, I should delete all temp files.

Comment: Does process create temp files with some name pattern? E.g temp_01.txt etc.

Comment: @bodo yes, they starts with .com.folder.<UID>

Comment: So is it a problem to remove all files which contains this pattern and for better safety also check user who has created this file (In ideal case process should run with some special user created only for this kind of work).

Comment: @bodo the problem is to delete unused folders and those which are used now should stay

Comment: OK. Explain what does it means "unused"/"used" folder. Could you please provide some situation example?

Comment: @bodo, so when I'm talking about used folders, I mean folders wich is currently in use by the process. And unused are those which are left from the previous run. This external application is running in several instances, and some of them cannot be finnished correctly, so they do not delete created temp folders.

Comment: It's little bit obscure solution, but before you kill the process with concrete PID, try to find out which file it uses see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-get-list-of-open-files/

Parse the the output for files (their names have a pattern as you have mentioned) and remember somewhere. Kill the process and delete the files.

There should be a problem, if for example process leaked files during it's closing. But It's not yours case, isn't it?

Comment: @bodo thx, I think I'll do this in a such way).

Answer (score 0):

Run the other process in a `container`. The whole filesystem seen by that process goes away when the container goes away.

I am suggesting that you look into a `container` based solution for this.

See [docker](https://www.docker.com/)